# SSIS: how to handle a quote-qualified csv file with quotes inside quotes

Tags: ssis

I'm working in SQL Server 2008 R2.  I have an SSIS package that imports a csv file into a table.  The given csv file is quote-qualified.  Because the file is quote-qualified, in its corresponding flat file connection, I specified Text qualifier = ".  However, the import fails because of a particular row in the file.  The given row has quotes inside of quotes.  For example:

```
"a","1","","text""moretext","","1.0"
```

The package throws the error:

> The column delimiter for column <> was not found.

I still want the row (and rows like it) to be imported.  How can I handle this in SSIS?

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14815574/how-to-fix-the-embedded-text-qualifier-issue-while-exporting-data-to-csv-flat-fi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it with a flat file source.

You can write a custom script (either a complete script task or a script source component), or you can import it with BCP and a format file.